# Is the result of List<T>.FindAll guaranteed to be in the same order as the original list?

Tags: c#, list, lambda

If I've got a List with the following entries:

Apple
Banana
Grape
Cherry
Orange
Kiwi

Is the result of

```
fruit.FindAll(f => f.Length == 6)
```

guaranteed to always be

Banana
Cherry
Orange

or could the order be different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not guaranteed in the sense that it doesn't say it in the documentation, however if you look at how it's *currently* implemented, then yes, it'll always come back in the same order.

Here's how it's *currently* implemented:

```
public List<T> FindAll(Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (match == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this._size; i++)
    {
        if (match(this._items[i]))
        {
            list.Add(this._items[i]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

As you can see, it's a simple for loop that sequentially goes through the list, and adds the items that match.

Comment: Which implementation are you referring to? .net 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, mono? :)

Comment: @Rob: good point :) I've attached the current .Net 3.5 implementation.

Comment: Relying on the internals of someone else's code doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 4):

The current implementation will preserve ordering.

That being said, there is nothing in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) which guarantees that this will always preserve ordering.  It is possible that a future version could, theoretically, thread this routine, or some other similar function, which would break the ordering.  I would not rely on the order being preserved.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the [List<T>.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) documentation, the order of the returned items isn't specified, therefore if it does at present that's an implementation detail which is subject to change.

In short, yes, the order could be different.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `List<T>.FindAll` does not explicitly make this guarantee.  It does allude to it being ordered.  More importantly though the implementation of the method does return an ordered list and I find it hard to believe it would every be changed to anything else.  It would quite simply break too many people.  The lack of explicit wording in the documentation is probably an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) says that a linear search is performed, although it doesn't explicitly say that it is guaranteed to be in the same order.

Comment: Linear search refers to the efficiency of the algorithm used and provides no information regarding whether or not the algorithm preserves order.